# Trying to add two queries together

Tags: sql, informix

I'm trying to add one more column that is a count for the amount of rows left,
 I don't want include rows where my planned quantity matches completed quantity
(plan_qty != cmp_qty)

```
SELECT   od_f.ob_oid Order,
         Sum(plan_qty) Plan_Units,
         sum(cmp_qty) Completed_Units,
         Round(((Sum(cmp_qty)/sum(plan_qty)) * 100.00),2)Percent_Cmp,
         total_value Value,
         SUM(round(cmp_qty * unit_price,2)) cmp_value
FROM     od_f,
         om_f
WHERE    od_f.ob_oid = om_f.ob_oid
GROUP BY od_f.ob_oid, total_value
ORDER BY Percent_Cmp desc
```

Heres a query that returns the new column I want

```
 SELECT   count(od_rid)
 FROM     od_f
 WHERE    od_f.plan_qty != od_f.cmp_qty
 GROUP BY od_f.ob_oid
```

I can't add the above where statement because it effects my results.
I'm really not sure what to do, to combined these queries a subquery? some sorta union?  I'm lost on how to do this.
 Thank you for any help

Comment: Can't you join your first query with your second query? I.e. SELECT * FROM (Select1 body) a JOIN (Select2 body) b ON a.something = b.something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I understand you only want a count of rows where `plan_qty` is not equal to `cmp_qty`, try this:

```
SELECT   t.ob_oid                                       AS order,
         SUM(plan_qty)                                  AS plan_units,
         SUM(cmp_qty)                                   AS completed_units,
         ROUND(((SUM(cmp_qty)/SUM(plan_qty)) * 100),2)  AS percent_cmp,
         total_value                                    AS value,
         SUM(ROUND(cmp_qty * unit_price,2))             AS cmp_value,
         SUM(DECODE(plan_qty, cmp_qty, 0, 1))           AS rows_left
FROM     od_f t
         INNER JOIN om_f
            ON t.ob_oid = om_f.ob_oid
GROUP BY t.ob_oid, total_value
ORDER BY percent_cmp DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. I did have to remove the "rows_left" in groupby due to syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation for what you want. Although `COUNT()` with `CASE` might be sufficient, my best guess is `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT   od_f.ob_oid Order,
         Sum(plan_qty) Plan_Units,
         sum(cmp_qty) Completed_Units,
         Round(((Sum(cmp_qty)/sum(plan_qty)) * 100.00),2)Percent_Cmp,
         total_value Value,
         SUM(round(cmp_qty * unit_price,2)) cmp_value,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN od_f.plan_qty <> od_f.cmp_qty THEN od_f. od_rid END) as newcol
FROM od_f JOIN
     om_f
     ON od_f.ob_oid = om_f.ob_oid
GROUP BY od_f.ob_oid, total_value
ORDER BY Percent_Cmp desc;
```

You should also learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error with the line,  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN od_f.plan_qty <> od_f.cmp_qty THEN od_f. od_rid END)) as newcol. I'm using informix thats probably the issue.

Comment: This should work, just drop the extra `)` and in your case the `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

@GordonLinoff solution is good for you, but only if you want to count uniques od_rid , this solution works for both cases, use a correlated query:

```
SELECT   t.ob_oid Order,
         Sum(plan_qty) Plan_Units,
         sum(cmp_qty) Completed_Units,
         Round(((Sum(cmp_qty)/sum(plan_qty)) * 100.00),2)Percent_Cmp,
         total_value Value,
         SUM(round(cmp_qty * unit_price,2)) cmp_value,
         (SELECT  count(f2.od_rid) FROM od_f f2
          WHERE f2.plan_qty != f2.cmp_qty and f2.ob_oid = f.ob_oid) as newcolumn
FROM     od_f t
         INNER JOIN om_f
ON       t.ob_oid = om_f.ob_oid
GROUP BY t.ob_oid, total_value
ORDER BY Percent_Cmp desc
```

Comment: This works but it returns a total in the column, is there a way to add a group by on the inner query? I tried but got a error 'subquery has returned not exactly one row'

Comment: Its not a total, its a count for each ob_oid .. exactly the same as your query @CharlesCooper

Comment: Here's a picture of what it looks like on my side, the first one is your query and the 2nd one is mine. http://imgur.com/a/gaDHd

Comment: Can't go inside this site

Comment: Weird, this should work also. Did you removed the `and f2.ob_oid = f.ob_oid` on the subquery?